# How to get a String output for lines instead of Tuples?

Tags: python, string, tuples

My code produces an error: How to get a String output for lines instead of Tuples?

```
def html_lines(file_count, content_in_dictionnary):

table_line = "".join(["<tr> <th> </th><th> ",
                      "</th> <th>".join([key for key in content_in_dictionnary]),
                      "</th></tr> "]),

for x in range(file_count):
    table_line += "".join([
      "<tr><td>Line_number",
      str(x + 1),
      "</td> <td>",
      "</td> <td>".join([content_in_dictionnary[key][x] for key in content_in_dictionnary]),
      "</td> <td></tr>"]),
return table_line
```

after debugging this section, i'm getting a `tuple` type on each line while i want a `string` type.

Comment: remove the stray comma on second to last line

Comment: `"</td> <td></tr>"]),` and `"</th></tr> "]),`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two comma trailing these line of code, remove them:

This one:

```
table_line = "".join(["<tr> <th> </th><th> ",
                      "</th> <th>".join([key for key in content_in_dictionnary]),
                      "</th></tr> "]),  # <-- here
```

and that one:

```
table_line += "".join([
  "<tr><td>Line_number",
  str(x + 1),
  "</td> <td>",
  "</td> <td>".join([content_in_dictionnary[key][x] for key in content_in_dictionnary]),
  "</td> <td></tr>"]),  #<-- here
```

tuples are defined by a comma placed after a value.

Comment: Doing that gave me this error :TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "unicode") to tuple

Comment: hehe, you had two trailing commas, see answer.

Comment: Cheers these 2 commas gave me headache.